# On Vanishing Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: terminology, riemannian-geometry

If a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ has a vanishing Riemann curvature tensor, then what

i) does this imply for the manifold? and

ii) What is such a manifold called?

Comment: For homogeneous manifolds it's isometric to a quotient of the euclidean space by a discrete group.

Comment: @user40276 That's true when $\mathcal{M}$ is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is called "locally flat" or "locally Euclidean". Its metric is locally isometric to the standard metric on $R^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold. Without further hypothesis, this does not tell you much. Suppose however, that the metric is *complete* (e.g. the manifold is compact). Then $(M,g)$ is the quotient of the Euclidean $n$-space by a properly discontinuous group of isometries acting freely. Topologically, it follows that such a manifold is finitely covered by the product $T^k\times R^{n-k}$. Take a look at the book

J. Wolf, "Spaces of constant curvature"

for details.

Comment: Is $T^k$ the $k$-dimensional torus?

Comment: Thanks! I was just a bit confused.

Comment: Not a problem. Spivak, of course, is another great source.

Comment: Thanks for the great references - I'll try my best to find them (I'm an independent learner).

Comment: Then, my suggestion is to start with do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry", it is the quickest and least technical introduction to the subject I know.